# need help on split row in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, unnest

I have a following table and I need to split row by role_collection value:

```
name   role_collection     date
------------------------------------
raj    3,5                 2018 6 12
gopi   2,3,6               2018 6 12
mani   3,4,5,7             2018 6 12
```

now I need output like this:

```
name   role   date
------------------------
raj    3      2018 6 12
raj    5      2018 6 12
gopi   2      2018 6 12
gopi   3      2018 6 12
gopi   6      2018 6 12
mani   3      2018 6 12
mani   4      2018 6 12
mani   5      2018 6 12
mani   7      2018 6 12
```

Comment: can you add the query to recreate your table. ad please fix the formatting. So we can easily replicate the data

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column to begin with. If you had properly normalized your data model, you wouldn't need to "split" the values now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Assuming you have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE t (name TEXT, role_collection TEXT, d DATE);
```

And your sample data:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('raj','3,5','2018-6-12'),
                     ('gopi','2,3,6','2018-6-12'),
                     ('raj','3,4,5,7','2018-6-12');
```

Create an array with your comma separated role_collection values using [`STRING_TO_ARRAY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html) - in case the column `role_collection` ins't already of type `TEXT[]` or `VARCHAR[]`. Then using [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html) you can extract all elements of this array, as shown here:

```
SELECT name, UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(role_collection,',')),d 
FROM t;
 name | unnest |     d      
------+--------+------------
 raj  | 3      | 2018-06-12
 raj  | 5      | 2018-06-12
 gopi | 2      | 2018-06-12
 gopi | 3      | 2018-06-12
 gopi | 6      | 2018-06-12
 raj  | 3      | 2018-06-12
 raj  | 4      | 2018-06-12
 raj  | 5      | 2018-06-12
 raj  | 7      | 2018-06-12
(9 Zeilen)
```